# Mosek and Code::Blocks, first steps - trouble compiling

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, mosek

I'm having trouble compiling a Cpp code in Code::Blocks, using windows (idk if thats relevant) and the Mosek library.

The first step i did was to add the path to the library through Project->Build options...->Search directories-> compiler: Policy "append target options to project options", adding the following path:"........\Program Files\Mosek\7\tools\platform\win64x86\h" (fyi at first ive used "/" instead of "\" but then somewhere i've read that in windows i should put the other way around, so i did the change. Either way the problem persists.)

But then it wouldn't recognize any command coming from Mosek library - the error would be "undefined reference".

Then i've tried to solve this issue by adding the folder where the mosek.h file is to Code::Blocks, through Project->Build options...->Linker settings: Policy "append target options to project options", linking mosek.h

But now the program informs me the following error: file ld.exe, message "cannot find -lmosek.h".

I'm really new to all of these, and tried to solve those googling it but i don't know what else to do. can someone please help me?

Comment: It should not matter if you use '/' or '\' as the path separator.

Comment: ***inking mosek.h*** Header files don't get linked. So this is your problem. You add libraries to your linker settings.